# How to add empty data in first of JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I got JSON data in PHP like this:

```
echo json_encode($jps_item);
```

```
[{"NO":"1","ID_OBJECT":"A045"},{"NO":"2","ID_OBJECT":"A049"}]
```

I'd like to make it the JSON like this:

```
[{"NO":"NULL","ID_OBJECT":"NULL"},{"NO":"1","ID_OBJECT":"A045"},{"NO":"2","ID_OBJECT":"A049"}]
```

I need an empty JSON for my loop. How do I convert it?

Comment: Second JSON isn't valid. JSON values should wrapped in double quote

Comment: @Mohammad thanks. I've edited it

Comment: There are two solutions: first, you can add the dummy object on the server side (the part that gives you the JSON); otherwise, you can create an array, add the dummy object and then move the new received objects here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed `jps_item` is your array. Just add an empty field in the beginning of it before encoding.

```
 <?php
$jps_item = [
    ["NO"=> "1","ID_OBJECT" =>"2"],
    ["NO"=> "3","ID_OBJECT" =>"4"]
];

$jps_item[-1] = [
    "NO"=> "NULL",
    "ID_OBJECT" =>"NULL"
];

ksort($jps_item);

echo json_encode($jps_item);
```

And the output is:

```
{"-1":{"NO":"NULL","ID_OBJECT":"NULL"},"0":{"NO":"1","ID_OBJECT":"2"},"1":{"NO":"3","ID_OBJECT":"4"}}
```

Comment: how to move it to the first place without adding the numbering ( "-1","0","1")

Comment: Not sure how the *answer will do the job for you* as it comes out with exact thing in your answer whereas they don't want the keys - especially the -1 key.

Comment: That was what the OP requested that he just does not want the -1 key. The rest is like he asked. In that case the @Praveen Kumar answer will fit him more.

Answer (score 0):

To make a generic solution, this creates a blank entry by taking the keys from the first element of the main array ( using `array_keys($jps_item[0])`) and creates an empty array using `array_fill_keys()`.

It then merges this blank with the main data using `array_merge()`...

```
$blank = array_fill_keys(array_keys($jps_item[0]), NULL);
echo json_encode(array_merge([$blank], $jps_item));
```

This means that if you change your main array, the blank will adjust itself.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try **array_unshift()** function. Check below code

```
$data_array2 =  array(
    'NO' => 'NULL',
    'ID_OBJECT' => 'NULL',
  );


array_unshift($jps_item, $data_array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert JSON to array using `json_decode()` and add new empty item to first 
of array using `array_unshift()` and then convert array to json using `json_encode()`

```
$json = '[{"NO":"1","ID_OBJECT":"A045"},{"NO":"2","ID_OBJECT":"A049"}]';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
array_unshift($arr, [
    "NO" => "NULL", "ID_OBJECT" => "NULL"
]);
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Lg7Yj)